# How to use Time Machine backup when hard drive is broken?

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine, restore, recovery

I have a MacBook Pro which I use Time Machine to back up usually weekly. Its hard drive broke recently.  I got an exactly same hard drive and installed it into the laptop.  How do I restore the computer into the most recent state using the Time Machine backup which was made when the old hard drive was installed?

Is there a better way to achieve the recovery than what I'm planning to do here?

Comment: Cmd/R at the chimes will give you recovery options, including Time Machine - see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314

Comment: I tried Cmd+R, nothing happened.  I probably don't have recovery partition somehow?

Comment: If you replaced the HDD, there will be no recovery partition.

Comment: If replacing it back is part of a viable solution, I can certainly easily do it, but is it?

Comment: How old is the Mac? Cmd/R ought to work even with a completely unformatted drive; rather than the built-in recovery, it should go to Internet Recovery, on any machine newer than Lion [or Snow Leo plus a patch] It also ought to be able to boot from the Time Machine volume itself.

Comment: MacBook Pro (15-inch, Early 2011).  I don't know what was installed originally.  Before failure, it was OS X 10.10.2 or 10.10.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic TimeMachine recovery procedure boils down to:

1) boot from Recovery/Installation media
2) make use of the Disk Utility (I recall under the tools menu option of the installation USB/DVDs) to format/partition the new disk
3) Then select/choose the Restore/transfer option where you can then select the TimeMachine (Or Migration Assistant) to restore from.

The problems I don't have an answer to as I've never done that in my setups:

a) recovery of the Recovery partition... I usually were doing "upgrades", thus I did fresh installs, and then I restored the TimeMachine specific files, or I used the "Migration Assistant" to restore the applications/users as need be

b) You didn't specify the version, which might mean different issues w.r.t. the medium, ie. USB/DVD/etc. Creating a USB boot image is outside the scope of *this* question and answer ;)